# why it's show up wrong number?

Tags: python, python-2.7

- it's not show up the largest number*
- if i insert these numbers for example (1,3,8,4,18,2,6,), it print 8 not 18

```
maximum=None
while True:
    num= raw_input('Enter Number : ')
    if num== 'done':
        break
    if num > maximum:
        maximum=num
        
print ('max is', maximum)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe you should convert the input to integers? `8` is greater that `18` when sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: @БогданОпир I'll work on that, thanks

Comment: @MarkM Not working

Comment: I am trying to get the largest number, in the list of numbers that the user insert it @AvenDesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks like, you are trying to get the maximum value of an input. From my view, your code looks completely  wrong, so I'll help you fix it.

Firstly, here is how I would do it (sorry Stack Overflow wouldn't let me paste this as code):

[image: I had to post it as an image]

Now, let me explain it to you.

Line 1, defines a function which will help us turn our input into an array, which will be needed later on.
Line 2 creates an empty list which we call 1st.
Line 4 splits the input by the comma and adds each value as an INTEGER to lst, using a for loop.
Line 5 returns the list back.

That's the end of the function. Next, we define 2 crucial variables.

Line 7 calls the input_to_list function and sets num as the list from our input.
Line 8 sets the maximum value to 0, which is basically the same as 0. The reason I didn't use None is because None is not an integer, and so it would return an error in a later line.

That's the variables defined. Next, we perform a loop that gets the maximum value.

Line 10 initiates a for loop that loops for every item in the list, num.
Line 11 checks to see if the value of the item in the array is larger than the maximum, which is 0, the lowest possible number.
Line 12 sets the new maximum to the value of the item if i is greater than maximum.
Because it's a for loop, it does this exact condition for every item in the loop.

Example:
Say we have a list which is [1, 5, 3, 12, 9]. This is what the program does.
Is 1 > 0. Yes. So `maximum = 1`.
Is 5 > 1. Yes. So `maximum = 5`.
Is 3 > 5. No. So `maximum still = 5`.
Is 12 > 5. Yes. So `maximum = 12`.
Is 9 > 12. No. So `maximum still = 12`.

Therefore, the maximum must be 12.

Finally, in line 14, we print it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate that, but I am a beginner and I want to know how to solve this problem with (while) function

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: It wouldn't let me add any code for some weird reason sorry.

Comment: Hi @ThePilotDude: would you add the text into the question by way of an edit? It really will work. Please ping me after you have done that, and I'll tidy it up if necessary.